# WD MyCloud scheduled backup of selected folders only - is it possible?

Tags: backup, external-hard-drive

Is it possible to set up WD MyCloud in such way, that some selected folders (and not all of them) are automatically backed up to connected external USB drive?

I'd like to keep my photos on it and I really don't like the fact, that it has only one drive. On the other hand, I don't see any reason to waste backup drive for iTunes library and so on.

Comment: Happy New Year, @krzysiek! What is the backup software that you are using with your WD My Cloud? I'd suggest you check our [WD Learning Center](http://setup.wd2go.com/?mod=faqs&device=mc&faq=backItUp) for some backup ideas. If you are using our WD SmartWare backup tool, I'd suggest you check this tutorial about [How to backup specific files & folders](https://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=7069). Hope this helps you. Let me know if you have any additional questions! :)

Comment: I'm afraid, that you misunderstood my question. I'm not asking, how to backup files on my computer, but how to backup files, that are stored on MyCloud device...

Comment: My bad, @Krzyseik! I just saw your first question. I believe there is a way for you to accomplish such a backup using the built-in My Cloud utility called 'Safepoint' if your NAS device is the single bay WD My Cloud. You should be able to see this feature in the My Cloud Dashboard. Here's our KB tutorial on [How to create a Safepoint backup of My Cloud](https://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=10428). Hope this was helpful. Let me know if you encounter any difficulties. Good luck! :)

Comment: @SuperSoph_WD Safepoint allows you to do mirror of your device. It doesn't allow you to select only few folders and backup them (backup is not the same as mirror). Is it really so hard to read and understand the question, you're trying to answer? I believe now I know, why you put your answers in comments, and not as answers... And you're an official WD representative... It only confirms, that I don't want to use WD MyCloud and nobody should, I guess...